# springboot HealthActuator NoSuchBeanDefinitionException No bean named 'healthEndpoint' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am migrating project from spring boot version 2.1.3 to spring boot version 2.3.4.

During bootrun I am getting below error

```
[ERROR] 2021-05-11 14:06:04 o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler [scheduling-1]: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'healthEndpoint' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy$LookupOverrideMethodInterceptor.intercept(CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy.java:242) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at com.banato.rate.submit.ok.jmx.HealthActuator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67bbc5e4.getActuatorHealthEndpoint(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
        at com.banato.rate.submit.ok.jmx.HealthActuator.health(HealthActuator.java:36) ~[main/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
    <==========---> 80% EXECUTING [8m 35s]
```

The is the scheduler its trying to get ActuatorHealthEndpoint and return the health status. While trying to lookup the healthEndpoint during bootrun its failing with the above error. Any suggestion how to resolve this please?

```
  package com.banato.rate.submit.ok.jmx;
    
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Lookup;
    import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
    import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint;
    import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import com.banato.jmx.HealthMonitoringMBean;
    
    /**
     * Health actuator component that handles monitoring Spring HealthIndicator
     */
    @Component
    public class HealthActuator {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HealthActuator.class);
    
        // This is a singleton instance hence updates will get reflected automatically to the jmx server
        @Autowired
        private HealthMonitoringMBean healthBean;
    
        /**
         * Check the health of Spring Boot actuator interfaces Mongo, Rabbit...
         * 
         * @return
         */
        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
        public HealthMonitoringMBean health() {
            Health health = (Health)getActuatorHealthEndpoint().health();
            boolean isReady = Status.UP.equals(health.getStatus());
    
            healthBean.setBusy(!isReady);
            
             healthBean.setBusyReason("{" + health.getDetails().entrySet().stream()
              .map(entry -> "\"" + entry.getKey() + "\": \"" + entry.getValue() + "\"")
             .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "}");
             
            healthBean.setHealth(true);
            healthBean.setHealthReason("Reaching this endpoint implies we are live");
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("HealthMonitoringMBean = " + healthBean);
            }
    
            return healthBean;
        }
    
        /**
         * Returns the endpoint for health actuator
         * 
         * @return
         */
        @Lookup("healthEndpoint")
        public HealthEndpoint getActuatorHealthEndpoint() {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Below is the properites

```
# ----------------------------------------
# ACTUATOR PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
management.security.enabled=false
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=jolokia
management.endpoints.jmx.unique-names=true
management.server.port=9012
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Here is the HealthMonitoringMBean

```
package com.banato.jmx;

import java.io.File;

public class HealthMonitoring implements HealthMonitoringMBean {

    private boolean health = true;
    private String healthReason;
    private boolean busy = true;
    private String busyReason;
    private boolean outOfMemory = false;
    
    public void setHealth(boolean health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public void setHealthReason(String healthReason) {
        this.healthReason = healthReason;
    }

    public void setBusy(boolean busy) {
        this.busy = busy;
    }

    public void setBusyReason(String busyReason) {
        this.busyReason = busyReason;
    }

    public void setOutOfMemory(boolean outOfMemory) { this.outOfMemory = outOfMemory; }

    @Override
    public boolean getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHealthReason() {
        return healthReason;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBusy() {
        return busy;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBusyReason() {
        return busyReason;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getOutOfMemory() { return outOfMemory; }

    public String toString(){
        return "\nHealth: " + health + "\nHealthReason: " + healthReason +
                "\nOutOfMemory: " + outOfMemory +
                "\nBusy: " + busy + "\nBusyReason: " + busyReason + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could pls post HealthMonitoringMBean also for clarity

Comment: @DineshDontha - posted HealthMonitoringMBean .

Comment: Have you defined the bean of HealthEndpoint in your application? Sthg like `@Bean
    public HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint()`